# Files exclusion (custom and transient) from build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake, googletest

I have many C++ (`Google Test`) source files in my `Visual Studio`solution  and I want to have the possibility to keep only a few for the build (to focus on the problem), but also to come back quick enough (two times by day) to the initial configuration.

We are using, more or less, about three solutions: `Visual Studio`, `CMake` and `QT` (but I could add yet another one). I never used `QT`, so the other two solutions I see are:

- `Visual Studio`: folders are useless, but I can select files and exclude them from build. But these changes are saved in vcproj so I have to pay attention not to save them on the version control, which is annoying.
- `CMake`: easy change the `CMakeLists.txt` (comment lines with the sources folders), but I always have the version control problem ... maybe I can configure the excluded files in a custom (user) file. Advantage: I can generate only what I want, more flexible and not so boring like the previous one.

By example, if I do not want the sources in src_2:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES_1
${SOURCE_BASE_DIR}/src_1/*.cpp
${SOURCE_BASE_DIR}/src_1/*.h
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES_2
${SOURCE_BASE_DIR}/src_2/*.cpp
${SOURCE_BASE_DIR}/src_2/*.h
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES_3
${SOURCE_BASE_DIR}/src_3/*.cpp
${SOURCE_BASE_DIR}/src_3/*.h
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_TEST_NAME}
${SRC_FILES_1}
# next line is commented
# ${SRC_FILES_2}
${SRC_FILES_3}
)
```

Is there another solution or a way to improve one of these proposed here?

Comment: So there are cpp files you don't want to compile sometimes? and sometimes you do? would a variable added to the cmake command be OK? So you can switch them on/off.

Comment: I added a sample ... adding a sample here - now that's a challenge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this with a cmake variable.

```
option(BUILD_TESTS "builds test cpp files" ON)
```

This adds an option for your cmake file. It defaults in this case to ON you can change that though. Now lets get on:

```
if(BUILD_TESTS)
    set(TEST_CPP_FILES test1.cpp test2.cpp)
endif(BUILD_TESTS)

add_executabe(foo bar.cpp bar1.cpp $(TEST_CPP_FILES))
```

Here you define a variable with the source file of your tests (or whatever source files you want to build when the `BUILD_TESTS` is `ON`. These then get added to the target. If `BUILD_TESTS` is off this variable will be empty.

now to change the Value you can run

```
cmake <...>  -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF
```

Or with `ON` if you want to turn them back on again. You also can keep the change in version control because it will default to `ON` and you need to explicitly disable it.

You can also exclude whole subdirectories or targets with this in the if statement if you not just only want to exclude source files.

**EDIT:**

For your example it could look like this:

```
if(BUILD_TESTS)
    file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES_2
    ${SOURCE_BASE_DIR}/src_2/*.cpp
    ${SOURCE_BASE_DIR}/src_2/*.h
    )
endif(BUILD_TESTS)
```

`SRC_FILES_2` should be empty afterwards.

Comment: Yes, I could add a variable for each "folder" with test files and the version control problem is solved. The only problem is that I need dozens of them.

Comment: You can have only 1 variable which just disables them all, if that would make sense.

Comment: @Liviu I edited my answer with how it could look with your example

Comment: I cannot disable them all because I want to run some tests (my solution/project consists of tests), but I can group them (src_1, src_2, src_3). And if I really want  to keep only one file inside of a group , then I can change the CMakeLists.txt, generate my solution and revert the change.

Comment: I like the solution, I will try it for a week or two and if there's no other problem or solution, I will accept your kind answer, thanks

Comment: @Liviu an alternative would be to have multiple test executables and you only build the ones you need.